# The steps to becoming an iPhone Developer

Tags: iphone

First some background:

The company I work for have decided to create an iPhone App for our main product and nominated me to do this work.  I've been a professional C# developer for over 5 years and although I have used other languages (Java, C++ etc), I have not used them to a professional standard and not for many years.  As for Mac/iPhone development I have never even used a Mac and have an Android phone.

My company are happy for me to go on any needed courses, buy any required books etc, to speed up the learning curve.

My first task is researching what I need (equipment, IDE's, SDKs) and what learning material to use (books, forums, courses - we're London based but if the course is good enough they might put me on a plane).

Of course I will be trawling the internet for some of these answers but I thought I can't hurt to consult the considerable knowledge of stack overflow (kissing ass I know!).  Plus I'm sure there will be many people like me who could do with pointing in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started With iPhone Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development)

Comment: Thanks for the link, searched but missed that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was at the Stackoverflow DevDays event in London last year and there was an excellent presentation by Phil Nash which he has up [here](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2009/10/31/devdays-slides.html) describing starting programming for the iPhone platform.

That's probably a good place to start. The main things I took from it were that you needed a Mac, XCode and a jump start (read: mind-meld) in Objective-C!

EDIT: worth checking out the offical Apple [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) site too.